# How do I execute this EJB method at startup?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I'm at a loss here. All externalities aside, this is an EJB supposed
to run att deployment on a Wildfly 8.2.1.Final, but Wildfly isn't even
calling the constructor, as is apparent from the `Exception` which is never thrown.

The bean is initializing a Timer and this is supposed to repeat some
periodic tasks iven in a configuration file. All that works in a Java
SE environment but most parts of it is cut out to eliminate distractions from the problem.

```
package jollobajano.bedtime.service.cleanupdaemon;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.ScheduleExpression;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.Timeout;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.slf4j.Logger;

import jollobajano.bedtime.service.cleanupdaemon.config.CronExpression;
import jollobajano.bedtime.service.cleanupdaemon.config.JobConfiguration;
import jollobajano.bedtime.service.cleanupdaemon.config.ProducedConfig;
import jollobajano.bedtime.service.cleanupdaemon.config.ScheduleExpressionProvider;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class ScheduledCleanupBean {

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    private Timer timer;

    @Inject
    @ProducedConfig
    private JobConfiguration configuration;

    @Inject
    private ScheduleExpressionProvider scheduleExpressionProvider;

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    public ScheduledCleanupBean() {
        System.err.println("### Constructing a ScheduledCleanupBean ### MATS");
        if (true) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("This is supposed to work, no?");
        }
    }

    @javax.ejb.PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.err.println("### Initializing a ScheduledCleanupBean ### MATS");
        if (configuration != null) {
            CronExpression cron = configuration.getCron();
            ScheduleExpression schedule = scheduleExpressionProvider.getScheduleExpression(cron);
            timer = timerService.createCalendarTimer(schedule);
            log.info("{} initialised.", this.getClass().getName());
        } else {
            log.info("{} not initialised. No configuration file found.", this.getClass().getName());

        }
    }

    @javax.ejb.PreDestroy
    public void exit() {
    }

    @Timeout
    public void execute(Timer timer) {
        for (String select : configuration.getSelect()) {
            log.info("SELECT: {}", select);
        }
    }

}
```

I will not bore you with the entire log but it is mentioned in two
contexts so that indicates to me that the bean is found and registered
in some aspect.

```
 of type org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
2017-02-06 10:37:28,052 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.ImplicitLocalViewProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-12) Bean: ScheduledCleanupBean will be marked for (implicit) no-interface view
2017-02-06 10:37:28,057 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-12) JNDI bindings for session bean named ScheduledCleanupBean in deployment unit deployment "bedtime2-application-2.0-SNAPSHOT.war" are as follows:

    java:global/bedtime2-application-2.0-SNAPSHOT/ScheduledCleanupBean!jollobajano.bedtime.service.cleanupdaemon.ScheduledCleanupBean
    java:app/bedtime2-application-2.0-SNAPSHOT/ScheduledCleanupBean!jollobajano.bedtime.service.cleanupdaemon.ScheduledCleanupBean
    java:module/ScheduledCleanupBean!jollobajano.bedtime.service.cleanupdaemon.ScheduledCleanupBean
    java:global/bedtime2-application-2.0-SNAPSHOT/ScheduledCleanupBean
    java:app/bedtime2-application-2.0-SNAPSHOT/ScheduledCleanupBean
    java:module/ScheduledCleanupBean

2017-02-06 10:37:28,135 DEBUG [org.wildfly.jberet] (MSC service thread 1-9) Creating batch environment; ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.bedtime2-application-2.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader
2017-02-06 10:37:28,137 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbClientContextSetupProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-14) Deployment unit deployment "bedtime2-application-2.0-SNAPSHOT.war" doesn't have any explicit EJB client context configured. Falling back on the default service jboss.ejb3.ejbClientContext.default EJB client context service
2017-02-06 10:37:28,137 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbClientContextSetupProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-14) Registering EJB client context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@63a2929d for classloader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.bedtime2-application-2.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader
2017-02-06 10:37:28,137 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-14) Configuring component class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlFmtTLV named org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlFmtTLV
2017-02-06 10:37:28,149 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-14) Configuring component class: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter named org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter
2017-02-06 10:37:28,152 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-14) Configuring component class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.WhenTag named org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.core.WhenTag
2017-02-06 10:37:28,155 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-14) Configuring component class: org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.FileTag named org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.FileTag
2017-02-06 10:37:28,161 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-14) Configuring component class: org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.AnchorTag named org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.AnchorTag
2017-02-06 10:37:28,164 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-14) Configuring component class: org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.PasswordTag named org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.PasswordTag
2017-02-06 10:37:28,166 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-14) Configuring component class: org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.SubmitTag named org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.SubmitTag
2017-02-06 10:37:28,167 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-14) Configuring component class: jollobajano.bedtime.service.cleanupdaemon.ScheduledCleanupBean named ScheduledCleanupBean
2017-02-06 10:37:28,198 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-14) Security is *not* enabled on EJB: ScheduledCleanupBean, no security interceptors will apply
2017-02-06 10:37:28,204 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-14) Configuring component class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.el.fmt.FormatDateTag named org.apache.tag:
```

and later

```
2017-02-06 10:37:29,558 DEBUG [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-7) WELD-000106: Bean: Session bean [class jollobajano.bedtime.service.cleanupdaemon.ScheduledCleanupBean with qualifiers [@Any @Default]; local interfaces are []
```

I guess this is easy to spot with fresh eyes. Is there anyone that see my misstake?

Cheers
Mats

Comment: The constructor should be called. How is deployed your EJB? In a war? Also, use `javax.annotation.PostConstruct`

Comment: Hi @ Rouliboy. The bean is deployed within a JAR inside a WAR. The JAR is also a bean archive and contains a `META-INF/beans.xml`. I have been switching back and forth between `@javax.ejb.PostConstruct` and `@javax.annotation.PostConstruct` to no consequence. Tried again just before answering you.

Comment: Do you have any web.xml?

Comment: There is a web.xml containing Struts and Sitemesh filters as well as a custom contextlistener ans a custom filter. The XSD-schema suggests Servlet 3.0. Nothing EJB-ish.

Comment: Both EJB 3.1 spec and Oracle Docs claims explicitly that the packaging of an EJB in a JAR in `WEB-INF/lib` should work, and it does as so much as that the bean is identified and registerred in the JNDI.

Comment: If the container is unable to create one or both of `JobConfiguration` or `ScheduleExpressionProvider` then it will not be able to complete the initialisation of your `ScheduledCleanupBean`. There's probably more information in the boring bits of the server log.

Comment: After reading tons of debug and trace logging: Wildfly finds, creates and registers the beans as I've hoped. I'm upgrading an old legacy struts application and there are loads of depebdebcies. I've got a hunch that there is some proxying going on and perhapps are the beans "kidnapped" by that. Some of the dependencies will be stripped off the project in time an Ihope that will bring me closer to a solution. Thanks for your input. I'm sorry if you feel I'be wasted your time. Cheers.